Is there a difference between "wsrep_cluster_address" parameter with a comma at the end and without?
I tried to figure it out because i saw 2 types of options to configure the "wsrep_cluster_address", is there a difference in configuring the "wsrep_cluster_address" with a comma at the end like so:
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.56.3,192.168.56.4,192.168.56.5,"

and without:
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.56.3,192.168.56.4,192.168.56.5"


I suspect no difference and perhaps 1 is documentation typo. Can you include some urls for correction?

From what I see from here, there is no difference between having a comma and not. it will finally use connect to connect to them.

Very interesting, considering the parsing of the address is in the Galera modules and not MariaDB.
